# Visualforce Email Template Invalid Field for SObject

Tags: visualforce, email-template, error, invalid

I have tried appending __c and __r as other threads have suggested, but I haven't had any luck yet--maybe I'm reading their advice incorrectly. I'm working on my first visualforce email template and when I attempt saving it I get an error message: "Error: Invalid field Display_Name for SObject Event"

The little bit of code that generates it is:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="You Are Registered!" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Event">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
Hello!
Thank you for registering for our {!relatedTo.Display_Name}.
```

What can I do to have it recognized as a valid field?

Comment: Can you confirm there is a field on `Contact` whose API Name is `Display_Name__c`?

Comment: No; that field is on Event, the "relatedToType"

Comment: Right, `Event`. That's what I meant. Can you confirm the exact API Name does, in fact, exist?

Comment: The exact API Name is "EventApi__Display_Name__c." I replaced it and got pretty much the same error message, "Invalid field EventApi__Display_Name__c for SObject Event"

Comment: I realized that I needed to get the API Name for the custom object that was the relatedToType correct: "relatedToType="EventApi__Event__c"". That helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every API Name must be exact. You should be able to run the following snippet in `Execute Anonymous` by putting the two together if you use `relatedToType="MyObject__c"` and `{!relatedTo.MyField__c}`:

```
SObjectField mergeField = MyObject__c.MyField__c;
```

In this case you need to double check `Event` and  `Display_Name__c`.